# What colour pink was used for the Seventh Doctor's TARDIS in the episode "The Happiness Patrol"

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

I have searched everywhere on the Internet that I could look and Google and many other websites list every colour blue the TARDIS has been:

[image: pantone blues]

For example the TARDIS blue was known as Pantone 295C in 2005-2010 and other various shades of blue and grey throughout the years.

But the seventh Doctor's TARDIS colour while it was on the happy planet when it was pink is nowhere.

What colour pink was used for the seventh Doctor's TARDIS in the episode "The Happiness Patrol"?

Comment: Im looking for the specific name of the color

Comment: What if the colour turns out to be called Danny Pink 

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's set in the future. It's more likely to be Orson Pink

Comment: People knock the Sixth Doctor, but at least he [**fixed**](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/50/4a/31504a420c7410fcc774fc14999c48f5.jpg) the Chameleon Circuits. I mean just look at [**her**](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T82R3S-k_7I/VTfVhfO_YII/AAAAAAAAP6w/gmOlPPxdEFk/s1600/tardis1.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Something around [Pantone 194C](https://store.pantone.com/uk/en/colorfinder/index/acfproduct/code/194+C)

[image]

It's hard to say for definite because the colour was only used in one episode in one particular set of lighting (and largely as a gag, based on the fact that they've not primered the TARDIS before coating it pink *over* the normal blue colour)